# Textbox loses focus in modal on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using AngularJS with UI Bootstrap to display a form in a modal dialog. However, any input loses focus when the scroll bar is clicked.

This happens if the scroll bar is associated with a div or with the window.

If the text input was not inside a modal then it maintains focus during scroll.

An example can be found at http://plnkr.co/edit/uaXiT1NedWjUm2DOKyrD?p=preview

There is nothing special about the input, it's as simple as can be

```
<input type="text" id="textinput" name="textinput"/>
```

Is there a way to maintain focus whilst the user scrolls?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Can you give me a reason why the focus should be hold text input? It seems natural to me because I click on elements other than input.

Comment: Because this is standard functionality when the input is rendered on a page (i.e. not in a modal). Try the search on this page, it doesn't lose focus when you scroll.

Answer (score 1):

It's not losing focus when you scroll, it's losing focus when you click on the scrollbar.  If you have a mouse wheel, for example, you can scroll the modal content without losing focus.

Basically clicking on the scrollbar is the same as clicking anywhere else on the modal that isn't in your input field.

It is true that some scrollbars won't do this (at least in Chrome).  I don't know what the difference is.  I have confirmed that it happens on anything set to overflow-y: auto or scroll, at least.  It's not related to AngularJS.

Click on the Contact Us button and see it happen in pure Bootstrap: http://www.bootply.com/8R8QWNO6Qv

I don't expect there will be an easy solution for you to prevent this that doesn't involve tracking where focus is and such; and that will be quite complicated on multi-input forms.